# Background для разрешений больше 1440x2560?

Tags: android, view, background, android-constraintlayout, density

Есть 3 imageview в итоге которые представляют общий background.
В целом работает нормально до разрешений 1440x2560.
На других устройствах с большим разрешением (н: 1440x3040 или 1080x2160)  появляются отступы.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_top"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/iv_center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_top_2x" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/iv_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_top"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_center_2x" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_bottom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_bottom_2x" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно организовать структуру в этом случае?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать размер окна таким же как размер bground

Comment: @drawable/bg_top_2x а это что? svg/xml или что-то иное?

Comment: @Pentiux png...

Comment: у пнг есть фиксированный размер. `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` вот это не позволяет стать больше по высоте, на сколько я понимаю. попробуйте поставить 0dp. Если не развернется, попробуйте завернуть во фрэйм и у него задавать 0dp а у img match_parent